# обращение к json по имени поля

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

есть такой json объект :

```
[
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Название 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Название 2"
    }
  ]
```

сейчас обращение происходит так :
импортирую файл

```
import Items from '/items.json';
```

и дальше получаю первый элемент так:

```
Items[0].title
```

есть какой то способ в js обращаться по имени поля чтобы писать не `Items[0]` , а `Items['Название 1']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Можно так например: `items.find(el => el.title === 'Название 1')`

  ```js
  const items = [{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Название 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Название 2"
    }
  ]

  const getItemByName = (arr, name) => arr.find(el => el.title === name);

  console.log(getItemByName(items, 'Название 1'));
  console.log(getItemByName(items, 'Название 2'));
  console.log(getItemByName(items, 'Название 3'));
  ```
- Если не хотите вызывать функцию вручную каждый раз, то можно с помощью [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) так:

  ```js
  const items = [{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Название 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Название 2"
    }
  ]

  const itemsByName = new Proxy(items, {
    get(target, prop) {
      return target.find(el => el.title === prop);
    }
  });

  console.log(itemsByName['Название 1']);
  console.log(itemsByName['Название 2']);
  console.log(itemsByName['Название 3']);
  ```
- Чтобы не терять время на поиски каждый раз, можно заранее подготовить нужную структуру

  ```js
  const items = [{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Название 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Название 2"
    }
  ]

  const itemsByName = {};

  for (const item of items) itemsByName[item.title] = item;

  console.log(itemsByName['Название 1']);
  console.log(itemsByName['Название 2']);
  console.log(itemsByName['Название 3']);
  ```

Comment: вот такие дела. спс. за подробный ответ

Comment: @spectre_it Всегда пожалуйста)